# How to locate the data column instead of character position NOT using loop to search in Perl and Bash?

Tags: regex, bash, perl

What I want to know is how to locate atom H location (as column number instead of character number) in a string/array using PERL or Bash? I tried to avoid unnecessary loops to search the H because my data has more than million lines.

I have research data shown below

```
FRAM_#     20000000      5000000(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT     16652      O      16654      H  1.036      8140     CA  2.586      7319     AL  1.963
```

Where, there are O,H,CA,and AL atoms. The first atom is target atom oxygen, and the rest of them are neighbors which bond with the target oxygen. Except for the first atom (oxygen), the integer number before each atom is the atom ID, and the float number after it is the bond length with the first atom O(ID=16652).

```
$line = 'FRAM_#     20000000      5000000(fs)  CN= 1    PRMRYTGT     16652'
        . '      O     16654      H  1.036      8140     CA  2.586'
        . '     7319     AL  1.963';
@values = split(/\s+/, $line);
my $bondlength;
my $neighbor_ID;
for (my $i = 10; $i <= $#values; $i = $+3) {
  if ($values[$i] eq 'H') {
    $neighbor_ID = $values[$i-1];
    $bondlength = $values[$i+1];
  } else {
    next;
  }
```

I can use loop to search the position of H in the array @values. However, is there any other way (not loop), like regex or BASH scripts, to get the position of H in the array? I highly appreciate it if you could provide me extra suggestion and help.

I want to find the hydrogen bond (bond length is longer than 1.5 angstrom) between H and target oxygen. So, I have to get the atom ID of H and related bond length. So, first, I need to find the location of H. And then locate the atom ID and related bond length. And then I can do further data analysis.

NOTE: I have data lines more than 1 million, thus, I have to consider the code efficiency. H is my target atom in this example. In the data lines, the amount of H may be various.

Comment: What do you want, value after H?

Comment: You need to give us more detail. For this line of input, what output do you want?

Comment: I need to get the atom ID (here is H) and bond length between  H and the target atom (here is oxygen).

Comment: I ask again. For this line of input, what output do you want?

Comment: @Leon Always post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I want to find the location of H. This is the first step for me to further analyze my data. In this question, I want to find hydrogen bond. So, first, I need to find the location of H. And then i can get the atom ID and related bond length. I tried to avoid the loop, because the time cost is O(n).

Comment: @Anubis, thanks for your suggestion. I added the codes to show what I want to do.

Comment: @Dave Cross, thanks for your question, I relied you. I want to get the location of H in an array. I need to locate H location first, and then I can get the bondlength and atom ID.

Comment: Use of regex will increase the complexity. Anyways, input line will be looped through no matter what tool/algorithm you choose

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks for your comment. How about using hash table which has O(1)? I am not sure how to assign a splitted data into a hash. Any suggestion?

Comment: Splitting data involves at least one loop.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. My goal is to reduce those unnecessary loops. For an instance, if I split the string into a harsh table (if I  could, I am searching the history questions and solutions), and then I can search the H in O(1). Any suggestion?

Comment: @oguzismail Yes. The function is same to my codes listed in my question. Anyway, thanks for your discussion.

Answer (score 0):

```
open(FH, "data.txt") or die "Can’t open data.txt: $!";

while(<FH>)
{
 if (@d=/\bO\s+(\d+)\s+H\s+(1\.[5-9]\d*|[2-9][\d.]*)/) {print "$_\n" for @d}
$ID=$d[0]
$len=$d[1]
}
```

each data line only results in ID, put in `$d[0]`, and bond length, in `$d[1]` if is greater/equal to 1.5, of `@d` array

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code, reformatted slightly for readability (whitespace is not in short supply!)

```
$line = "FRAM_#     20000000      5000000(fs)  CN= 1  PRMRYTGT     16652      O      16654      H  1.036      8140     CA  2.586      7319     AL  1.963";

@values = split(/\s+/, $line);

my ($bondlength, $neighbor_ID);

for (my $i = 10; $i <= $#values; $i += 3) {
  if ($values[$i] eq 'H') {
    $neighbor_ID = $values[$i-1];
    $bondlength = $values[$i+1];
  }
  else {
    next;
  }
}
```

The `else` clause in your loop is completely unnecessary. The loop will just go on to the next iteration anyway.

One obvious optimisation is to stop looking once you've found the hydrogen atom. So your code would look like this:

```
$line = "FRAM_#     20000000      5000000(fs)  CN= 1  PRMRYTGT     16652      O      16654      H  1.036      8140     CA  2.586      7319     AL  1.963";

@values = split(/\s+/, $line);

my ($bondlength, $neighbor_ID);

for (my $i = 10; $i <= $#values; $i = $+3) {
  if ($values[$i] eq 'H') {
    $neighbor_ID = $values[$i-1];
    $bondlength = $values[$i+1];
    last; # stop looking once you've found it
  }
}
```

I don't know if it's enough of an optimisation to solve all of your problems, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks for your reformation. Yes. It becomes clearer in this case. Unfortunately, this is not what I want. I hope to find another way to improve the code efficiency. This search is O(n). For an individual search, it is not a problem. However, for millions of data, it would cost more time. That is why I want to find another way to avoid such searching loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly the expected result for the given input.
If it is the pair of numbers before and after letter `H`, following will do.

```
sed -E 's/.*\s+(\S+)\s+H\s+(\S+)\s.*/\1,\2/' < input.txt
```

Sample input:

```
FRAM_#     20000000      5000000(fs)  CN= 1 PRMRYTGT     16652      O      16654      H  1.036      8140     CA  2.586      7319     AL  1.963
```

Sample output:

```
16654,1.036
```

Answer (score 0):

perl: use `firstidx` from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils)

```
use List::MoreUtils  qw/ firstidx /;

my $line = '...';
my @values = split ' ', $line;
my $h_idx = firstidx {$_ eq 'H'} @values;
print "H appears at index $h_idx\n";
```

This will use a loop [under the hood](https://metacpan.org/source/REHSACK/List-MoreUtils-0.428/lib/List/MoreUtils/PP.pm#L202). I don't see how you can avoid it. If your list was sorted, you could use a binary search, but your list is not sorted.

On the other hand, you don't need to split your line in to a list at all, which should save you some time:

```
my ($neighbour_id, $bond_length) = $line =~ /(\d+) \s+ H \s+ (\S+)/x;
return $neighbour_id if $bond_length > 1.5;
```